# Como modificar um objecto de Javascript com as mesmas chaves de um outro array com números?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tenho um objecto com 20 chaves no total, cada chave está associada a um valor mas, valor esse que não interessa de momento para a resposta. Assim está o objecto:

```js
var obj = {
   1: ...,
   2: ...,
   3: ...,
   ...,
   20: ...

}
```

Tenho também um *array* com números seguidos, assim:

```js
var myArray = [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 ]
```

Quero retornar o mesmo objecto (obj) mas com as *keys* iguais aos do meu *array*, exemplo:

```js
var obj = {
   10: ...,
   11: ...,
   12: ...,
   13: ...,
   14: ...,
   15: ...,
   16: ...,
   17: ...

}
```

Comment: Frederico, no [pt.so] você deve publicar somente em **português**. Use o botão [edit] para traduzir.

Comment: Tem razão Anderson, está corrigido!

Comment: Faltou o título xD

Comment: Agora sim é de vez xD Consegues me ajudar??

Comment: Ainda não. Seu objeto não parece ser um objeto válido no JS. Você cita que ele possui 20 chaves, mas ele mais parece um *array*. Um objeto relaciona uma chave com um valor e os seus objetos na pergunta não possuem valores.

Comment: Sim de facto cada chave está associado a um valor, mas de momento só quero trabalhar com as chaves e esconder aquelas que não estão no array. reformulei de modo a ser mais fácil de leitura.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você deve buscar as chaves do seu objeto, filtrar com base no *array* que possui e construir um novo objeto com as chaves restantes. Busque as chaves do objeto com `Object.keys`, filtre com `Array.prototype.filter` e crie um novo objeto com `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
const original = {
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'c',
  4: 'd',
  5: 'e'
}

const manter = ['1', '3', '5']

// Busca as chaves do objeto
const chaves = Object.keys(original)

// Filtra com base no array
const mantidas = chaves.filter(chave => manter.includes(chave))

// Monta um novo objeto
const resultado = mantidas.reduce(
  (novo, chave) => {
    novo[chave] = original[chave]
    return novo
  },
  {}
)

console.log(resultado)
```

Vale lembrar que no JavaScript as chaves de um objeto **sempre** serão *strings*, mesmo que você o cria com chaves do tipo inteiro. O motor do JS internamente faz o *cast* para *string* quando você não utiliza esse tipo, portanto o *array* de chaves que devem ser mantidas deve conter *strings* ou você pode adaptar a solução para fazer essa conversão, dado que `objeto[1]` será o mesmo que `objeto["1"]`, mas no *array* `[1]` não é o mesmo que `["1"]`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson!!!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que entendi o que você quer fazer, mas acredito que não tem como declarar um objeto dinâmico da maneira como descreveu. Então tente o seguinte:

```
let myArray = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]; //array c/ as chaves válidas
let obj = [{id:1,value:...},{id:2,value:...},{id:10,value:...}]; //remodelei seu objeto
//id é o valor correspondente às chaves do myArray
let newObj = []; //array do retorno
for(let key of obj) //foreach, cada chave do obj
{
   for(let id of myArray) //comparar c/ os n°s do myArray
   {
      if(key.id == id) //se o id for igual
      { 
         newObj.push(key); //adiciona ao obj de retorno
         break; 
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado !!